# array while loop output Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, while-loop

Ok, i got this working while loop that lets the user insert random numbers, if the number is 0 or if the loops length has been achieved then it will stop, now i have to output all the numbers that was inputed and the amount of the inputs (example 1, 2, 3 amount = 3). How do i output the array? i only get 0 from the println.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int [] a1 = new int[100];

    int i = 0;
    int tal;

    while(true){

        System.out.println("Insert number (0-end):");
        tal = scan.nextInt();

        if(tal == 0 || a1[i] == a1.length){
            break;
        }else{
            tal += a1[i];
        }


    }//End of while

    System.out.println("The inserted numbers are are: " + a1[i]);


}//
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: How do i output the inserted numbers (the array) i only get 0 from the println

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can figure it out on your own, try a little bit more. Just note that you are not using `i` variable properly.

Comment: @wanderlust Please be more careful with your edits. You've just *removed the question*.

Comment: @JonK Sorry, it looks like we got into collision, cause the question I've been edited, didn't have any question.

Comment: check your previous post, my answer also displays the values entered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, store tal in array and increment i every time you store. Finally iterate through array to print elements entered

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tset {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int [] a1 = new int[100];

        int i = 0;
        int tal;

        while(true){

            System.out.println("Insert number (0-end):");
            tal = scan.nextInt();

            if(tal == 0||i>=100){
                break;
            }else{
                a1[i]=tal;
                i++;
            }


        }//End of while


        System.out.println("The inserted numbers are are: ");
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
            System.out.println(a1[j]+"\t");

        }
        System.out.println("amount is: " +i);


    }//
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an ArrayList instead of an array to collect the number input and then iterate over it to print them use its built-in lenght method to output the amount

Comment: I can only use an array in this task

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues:

- You may want to put element you read into array like `a1[i] = scan.nextInt();` and initializing tal as 0 and using a1[i] in if condition instead of tal.
- You are not incrementing value of i and end's up overwriting the previous value.
- Once you come out of loop, you just print 0th value of array which i think you entered 0 and came out of loop.

You can over come these as below:

Just after `tal += a1[i];` increment value of i as:

```
i++;
```

Now to print your element, use a loop like:

```
System.out.print("The inserted numbers are are:");
for (int j=0; j<i; j++) {
    System.out.print(" " + a1[j]);
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: It kinda works but the problem is it outputs

The inserted numbers are 1, The inserted numbers are 2, The inserted numbers are 3, etc

instead of, the inserted numbers are: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Comment: I had duplicated "The inserted numbers are are:" part which i now removed. Check and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but this might help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] a1 = new int[100];

    int i = 0;
    int tal = 0;
    int tmp;
    do {
        System.out.println("Insert number (0-end):");
        tmp = scan.nextInt();
        a1[i] = tmp;
        tal += a1[i++];
    } while (tmp != 0 && i < a1.length);

    System.out.println("The inserted numbers are : ");
    for (int j = 0; j < i-1; j++) {
        if (j == i-2) {
            System.out.print(a1[j] + ".");
        } else {
            System.out.print(a1[j] + ", ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The sum is : " + tal);


}
```